# FSolve simultaneous equations in matrix form with matlab

Tags: matlab

I've seen several examples of fsolve in matlab, but can't seem to find any that show how to pass parameters in matrix form.

Here is my code.

```
[A,b] = equationsToMatrix(eq1,eq2)

X0 = [0 0]

fsolve([A,b], X0)
```

Here is the output

```
eq1 = - sx - sy/2 == 5 

eq2 = - (3*sx)/2 - (3*sy)/2 == 9 

A =

[   -1, -1/2]
[ -3/2, -3/2]


b =

 5
 9


X0 =

 0     0

Error using lsqfcnchk (line 109)
If FUN is a MATLAB object, it must have an feval method.

Error in fsolve (line 198)
    funfcn = lsqfcnchk(FUN,'fsolve',length(varargin),funValCheck,gradflag);

Error in SolveTesting (line 70)
fsolve([A,b], X0)
```

As you can see I've already got the system of equations in a nice format for solving, why isn't matlab accepting this?  I don't understand the point of the x0 argument either.  I'm providing a system of equations, so why would I need a starting point?

Comment: You need to supply a "ball park" starting point so the algorithm doesn't get confused by giant errors that will result from being very far from the answer.  The first parameter is supposed to be an evaluation function (which returns how far from the answer you are).  You can't just pass a matrix.  However, you can create an anonymous function and wrap your data in that.

Comment: Read http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html

Comment: Shouldn't the x0 have 4 variables then?  A min/max for both unknowns in the system?  I have of course referenced the help documentation and I don't understand it.  It's examples all directly supply the equations being evaluated.  I can't hard code the equations as they come from results of other code.

Comment: No, you are trying to solve for `sx` and `sy`.  That's two variables.  Your evaluation function should run them through your equations to generate `b`.  You then take `c = b - [5 9]` and come up with something that generates a single positive value.  *eg* `sum(c .* c)`.  That's your error.  `fsolve` tries to minimize this error.  You don't need that `A` matrix.  If you want to solve it in that way, you're looking in the wrong place.  `fsolve` is designed to minimize a system that might not have a 100% accurate solution.

Comment: What evaluation function?  I don't understand what this means.  The equations are in matrix form.  You said that x0 is a "ball park" figure, boundary conditions, which implies a range.  Hence you would need a min and max for each unknown being solved for.  Going into the problem I can predict a range, but I don't know the answer in advance to some % accuracy.

Comment: What is `c` what is `b`?

Comment: It looks like you are expecting an absolute result to solve the system of equations.  You should do gaussian reduction instead of using `fsolve`.  Discussing this further is just going to confuse you.

Comment: I appreciate your replies, but they aren't helping me.  I understand what fsolve does.  I'm not looking for an exact solution.  I'm just trying to figure out how to code it in matlab based on the format I have the equations in.  The example I'm giving is actually very simple compared to the real problem.  The real problem involves thousands of equations, for the sake of this discussion I've simplified it down to two, but the real matrix will have thousands of equations in it.  This is a coding matlab question, not a math question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Figured it out.**  Here's the deal.  The object passed to **fsolve** needs to be a pointer to a function.  This function needs to evaluate each of your equations in the system and return a matrix which contains a numerical result for each equation.  If all equations return zero the system is solved.

The function that you pass to fsolve can either be defined in a separate script or created in line if it's simple.

For example define:

```
function f = matrixfun(z,A,b)
    f = double(A) * [z(1);z(2)] + double(b);
end
```

And then call:

```
>> fsolve(@matrixfun,guess,[],A,b)

Equation solved.

fsolve completed because the vector of function values is near zero
as measured by the default value of the function tolerance, and
the problem appears regular as measured by the gradient.

<stopping criteria details>


ans =

4.0000   2.0000
```

Or you can just do this:

```
>> fsolve(@(z)double(A)*[z(1);z(2)]+double(b),[-5 -5])

Equation solved.

fsolve completed because the vector of function values is near zero
as measured by the default value of the function tolerance, and
the problem appears regular as measured by the gradient.

<stopping criteria details>


ans =

 4.0000   2.0000
```

** I pass A & b through double() because at first I was getting an error that fsolve wanted all values as doubles.